# Better to declare JavaScript Object inside for loop or outside in terms of time optimization

Tags: javascript, arrays, optimization, variable-declaration

Edit: This question is mainly focussed on should objects be declared inside a for loop (huge loop of an order of billion count) in each iteration or is it better to declare the object once outside for loop to save time during object declaration (time spent on memory allocation)  in each sprint.

I am trying to optimize my code by making sure that I don't spend any extra time allocating memory for objects declared inside the for loop in each iteration.

I have a long for loop (say order of billion) which creates huge objects in each array iteration and pushes those objects to an array. My question is, if it is better to declare the object inside for loop or declare it outside so that JavaScript runtime doesn't have to spend time allocating memory for the object in each sprint.

Here is something I tried for a loop of million count. Tried for billion count but it didn't complete on my computer:

```
//Case 1: Object declared outside the for loop
function createObjInForLoopWithVarDeclaredOutside() {

   var startTime = Date.now();
   var obj; //object declared here so that memory allocation is done one time

   var targetArray = [];

   for(var i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {

      obj = {};

      obj.id = i;
      obj.value = 'value :: ' + i;

      targetArray.push(obj);

  }

  var endTime = Date.now();

  var timeTaken = endTime - startTime;
  console.log('Time taken: ' + timeTaken);

}
```

Time taken by above program: 505 to 525 milliseconds

```
//Case 2: Object declared and defined inside for loop for each sprint
function createObjInForLoopWithVarDeclaredInside() {

   var startTime = Date.now();

   var targetArray = [];

   for(var i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {

      var obj = {};

      obj.id = i;
      obj.value = 'value :: ' + i;

      targetArray.push(obj);

   }

   var endTime = Date.now();

   var timeTaken = endTime - startTime;
   console.log('Time taken: ' + timeTaken); //486 to 509

}
```

Time taken by above program: 486 to 509 milliseconds

Can someone help explain which is a better approach to optimize the execution time? With the second approach where I declare the object inside the for loop, my concern is that this may take longer to run because every iteration, runtime has to allocate memory for new object which may take longer. However with my profiling data, it seems second approach of declaring object inside for loop is better. In terms of scoping, my personal favorite is to decalre variable when it's needed but for such huge for loops, I do want to look at various runtime optimizations.

I am not sure if this optimization is even needed in case if JavaScript optimizes the code before running them.

Comment: I would humbly like to ask for the reason on why this question is down voted? I am new to Stackoverflow but I tried my best to put all my analysis and sample code in my question to explain my problem. I would appreciate if I know what's missing here so that I can use that as an input for future. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are the same. `for` loops don't create a new scope so the variables are hoisted to the top of the containing function scope.

ex:

```
> i
undefined
> for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) { var test = i; }
undefined
> i
5
> test
4
```

As you can see, the variables `i` and `test` are hoisted to the global scope here. You might want to check out [**You Don't Know JS: Scopes & Closures**](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/scope%20%26%20closures/README.md) to get a better understanding.

Comment: thanks Jason for your reply! It helped to understand the concept of hoisting and scopes. BTW what is the format of the code in your post? Seems like you are trying to explain hoisting, it will further help if you add some comment in your code snippet.

Comment: @PrabhashRathore, the format is simply the output from either a browser console or Node's REPL. I'm glad this helped out your understanding and happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

Those are exactly the same. Variables declarations in JS are hoisted to the top of the surrounding function scope.

The actual allocation of the object is going to be the expensive part and you must do that every iteration.

Declaring the variable, at worst, puts a reference on the function stack. That's cheap regardless of how you do it, but since JS forces hoisting, the only way you could possibly do it more than once would be to split the object creation into another function. If you did that, on a billion iterations, the call overhead would kill performance by itself.

Comment: thanks for your reply! I didn't think about variable hoisting coming from Java background. Also since for loop doesn't create a new scope so it makes sense that both functions are doing the same.